# VBA Excel: Show visible cells in listbox only

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have the below mentioned code, I am trying to load filtered cells only into the listbox but I don't know why the below mentioned code is not functional.

Legend:

- PatternSearchButton is a button
- PatternTextBox is a textbox by which the user enters a value Which the Sheet will filter.
- WsLookup is a function which selects the sheet (completely functional)

  ```
  Private Sub PatternSearchButton_Click()

      Dim PatternInput As String, PatternCounter As Double, WsSelector As Worksheet
          PatternInput = PatternTextBox.Value

      Set WsSelector = WsLookup(GSMListType.Value)
          WsSelector.Range("F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=PatternInput

          PatternCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(4, WsSelector.Range("F:F"))

          With AvailableNumberList
              .Clear
              For k = 2 To PatternCounter + 1
                  .AddItem WsSelector.Range("A" & k).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
              Next k
          End With



  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Is `AvailableNumberList` a global object? If yes, what's its type? If not, what class is supposed to be?

Comment: @cst-link  `AvailableNumberList` is the list box itself

Comment: Is the code giving errors at the `.AddItem WsSelector[...]` line? And, since we're here, do you use `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: The list returns an empty result. I don't get errors but if I go to the sheet, I find the sheet filtered correctly. So the data is not showing. No, I don't use `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're are using *PatternCounter* as the upper limit in your `For .. Next` but this is being set using the `MAX` (e.g. *4*) subfunction of `SUBTOTAL`. This might work on sequential numbers in an unfiltered list but it is unlikely to be accurate in a filtered list. Using the `COUNT` (*2/102*) or `COUNTA` (*3/103*) subfunction might be more appropriate.

You were using `SUBTOTAL(4, ...)` so I would assume that you are dealing with numbers. Use a straight count on numbers on visible cells in column F and modify the remainder of the code to resemble this.

```
    PatternCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2, WsSelector.Range("F:F"))
    With WsSelector.cells(1,1).currentregion.offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        AvailableNumberList.Clear
        For k = 1 To PatternCounter
            AvailableNumberList.AddItem .cells(k, 1).Value
        Next k
    End With
```

Comment: This is what I need. I also want to filter a string, what would you suggest using instead of counta, it doesn't seem to be functional.

Comment: @mario R. - The above snippet was intended to be incorporated into the code you had in your original question which would have included the `.AutoFilter` statement. There isn't much to go on as far as *'filter a string'* is concerned beyond that. Could you amend your original question or start a new one with enough additional information to provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might stem from the fact that you add to the list box the value of a special cell that might not exist if the cell is hidden.

Try for the body of the `For` loop:

```
' ... previous code '
If Not WsSelector.Rows(k).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        .AddItem WsSelector.Cells(k, 1).Value
End If
' rest of the code ... '
```

Also, make sure that `AvailableNumberList` points to the correct object in your code.